# HTTP requests from Ionic 2 on device do not work

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I created my first Ionic 2 app. The app makes some HTTP requests to my API (the API is online, not localhost).

In my browser (ionic serve) everything works great.

But now I have built my first APK

```
cordova build android
```

and installed the app on my Galaxy S5

When the app is supposed to make HTTP requests it does nothing. I checked the server logs from the API and it receives nothing from the app.

I have the whitelist plugin installed:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.1" />
<access origin="*" />
```

I don't get any error messages, so I don't really know here to start debugging.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the javascript console for errors on your S5?

Comment: @almo could be content security policy issue. Check on this lines. Surely there should be error trace in device console. Check it out using chrome inspector

Answer (score 0):

- Have you checked INTERNET.PERMISSION on your android manifest?
- Have you checked Live debugging console for errors? (`ionic run android`)

Hope this might help!